# How does one release cache of application in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

In my project, I create an image control.  I also have a button that, when clicked removes the image.

I set the url of the image to null, and set the image control itself to null.  However, not  all memory of the Image control is released.  If I add more Image controls, my project will be very prone to run out of memory.

- When I start the app: memory usage = 5.218Kb
- When I remove the image control: memory usage = 5.416Kb

How does one release the memory / cache when the control has been removed or loaded again?
How can I manage the application's memory?

Comment: Show what you're doing. Don't just describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is still actual, but try this: [Image downloader with auto memory cleaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136160/image-downloader-with-auto-cleaning). Sample project here: https://simca.codeplex.com/