# Run throguh visual tree and set all Images to null

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, listbox, virtualization

I saw tons of threads with memory leaking while using images. 
So, is it a good idea just to have a general function, some kind of own GC, which would run at NavigatingFrom, find all images (even in templates of virtualized lists) and set them to null?

Comment: You can iterate through each element children in UICollection and check whether it is an image and handle it the way you like. I think this is one kind of solution.

Comment: @max I'm afraid, there's no UICollection on the WP7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an helper to iterate throught all the images of your page:

```
public IEnumerable<Image> GetAllImage(DependencyObject root)
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
            if (child is Image)
            {
                yield return (Image)child;
            }
            foreach (var image in GetAllImage(child))
            {
                yield return image;
            }

        }
    }
```

You can just call it with the root of your page as parameter and it should return all the images to you.

Comment: Sounds good. So, if i'd call it for the listbox, it should return all items images? Thanks, i'll try it.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you really have a page leak this will just fix the more important part of the leak (because it's what is taking the most space) but not the actual leak itself

Comment: Hm.. why? Afaik, problem is about auto-caching images data. Setting images to null would release them, isnt it?

Comment: yes setting it like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062820/clear-cache-in-window-phone-7) should release the image from the cache but I'm suspecting the reason they are kept in cache is because you have a memory leak for another reason

Comment: Yep, that's what i want to apply to all images in listbox. But what can be a reason then? I'm loading page with listbox, in WM's OnNavigatedTo(), i'm filling list, and clearing it in OnNavigatedFrom(). Actually, i want to do the same for pivots - that's why i asked question in the near thread ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895232/sending-loadingpivotitem-event-to-pivotitems-usercontrols )

Comment: Just another small question: why yielding while returning?

Comment: that's because i return a enumerable, like this when you iterate through the response it basically return the item element by element

Comment: Googled for additional information, looking like very usefull stuff.