# Master-detail pages memory leak

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-management, memory-leaks, mvvm-light

I have a master page with listbox of items (each one includes name, some details and image), and detail page for every item (larger image and more detailed description).

The problem is: while moving time forward-backward quite often, memory consumption grows, and slows down app.

Another problem is build-in cacher: i'm handling OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo in the viewmodel, and rebuild the list (now i'm looking the way to [free list images during OnNavigatedFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886640/run-throguh-visual-tree-and-set-all-images-to-null)), but sometimes, previous page is taken from cache.

Comment: If you don't share any code I don't see how we can help you find out where is the memrory leak.

Comment: But the most common case is event on long time object, so if you register event in you pages, you have to make sure you unregister them otherwise the event will keep a reference on your page

Comment: @BenoitCatherinet Yep, that's why i'm trying to avoid using events. I dont have any in my page. Just clean page with header and listbox, which leads to detail page.