# Sending LoadingPivotItem event to PivotItems (UserControls)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, navigation

So, i have Pivot and PivotItems as UserControls. 
I'd like to know, when every PivotItem is NavigatedTo and NavigatedFrom.

I made a base class (PivotItems are inheriting it), added there 2 methods (To and From), and i have LoadingPivotItemCommand() in the pivot, so i know, which PivotItem is loaded.

But how to broadcast this event to pivots? I tried some ways, but all of them are nulls.

```
void LoadingPivotItemCommand(PivotItemEventArgs args)
    {
        var b = args.Item.Parent as BaseUserControl;
        var a = args.Item.Content as BaseUserControl;
        var a1 = args.Item.Content as UserControl;

        var c = args.Item.DataContext as BaseUserControl;

        if (c != null) 
            c.OnPivotItemActivated();
    }
```

PivotItems are defined in xaml:

```
   <controls:PivotItem Header="{Binding Path=MainResources.Products, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Converter={StaticResource StringToLowerCaseConverter}}"
                            Name="PivotItemProducts">
            <Grid>
                <productsView:ProductUserControl />     
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

Comment: Edit the title to make it more descriptive, please.

Comment: @anderZubi Added. You're right: i guess, this one is better. Any suggestions on the question?

Comment: I don't really understand what your are trying to do? Can't you achieve your goal using SelectionChanged event of the Pivot item?

Comment: @anderZubi Yep, i can catch event in Pivot. I want also to notify PivotItem, that it should load or unload data.

Comment: @anderZubi Actually, the problem is to cast args.Item to BaseUserControl

Comment: where are you using BaseUserControl? Did you just put it inside a PivotItem?

Comment: @BenoitCatherinet I want to inherit UserControl's ViewModels from base class with 2 methods (NavigatedTo and NavigatedFrom), cast current UserControl to BaseUserControl and call those methods.

Comment: My question is how do you instanciate BaseUserControl, is it defined in xaml inside a PivotItem? (What is the relasionship between a Pivot and BaseUserControl?)

Comment: @BenoitCatherinet Yep, it is defined in xaml. I would update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing ProductUserControl is the one inheriting form BaseUserControl. If your BaseUserControl is always inside a Grid like in the xaml you show then you could just use :

```
var a1 = (args.Item.Content as Grid).Children[0] as BaseUserControl;
```

Otherwise if your UserControl can be place at different part inside the PivotItem then you can just use the function that [I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886640/run-throguh-visual-tree-and-set-all-images-to-null/18900950#18900950), just replacing Image by BaseUserControl.