# memory leak in window phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I tried to control the memory in our application. But the memory is not the same as when a new application starts.

Example:

In app, I have 2 Pages (MainPage.xaml and Page1.xaml).

Code in MainPage(.Xaml):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,223,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

and Page1.xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Button Content="add" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="remove" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,12,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button2_Click" />
        <ListBox Height="666" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,90,0,0" Name="lsbMyList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" />
    </Grid>
```

Page1: when I returned from the memory MainPage, my application increased from 1Mb to over 5Mb.

In listbox of Page1, I add an Image to listBox, when I Back Page , I set the image control to null URL and imageControl = null; memory is not reduced

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The question is unclear, please reformulate. I have the feeling that you expect that all memory related to page1 gets released by the time the control returns to main page. Even if forget about the app logic (which is not shown and which may contain explanation to your worries), you cannot make any statement about the memory without running GC (because the time when the objects get finalized is indeterministic).

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023879/how-does-one-release-cache-of-application-in-windows-phone-7.

Answer (score 2):

See instructions on releasing image memory at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

How are you confirming that the memory is from the image and not anything else you're using and possibly not clearing up?

Comment: i want release memory leak in my app. memory is not reduced when i Back Page. Matt Lacey, Please help me :D

Comment: Matt Lacey ! how to update Service References in code behind ?

Comment: For general tips on memory management I'd recommend using the profiler in the new tools RC to idenitfy issues. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: i'm using it in my app. and i use class MemoryDiagnosticsHelper.cs to memory my app. I tried to control the memory in our application. i have null all control in this second page before back to mainPage , but memory is not reduced when i Back Page